# tinymce, block remove of object?

Tags: jquery, tinymce

Hello i am using tinymce right now the latest version. I have a picture in my content, that i disabled from being resized.

Now, im wondering if there is a possible way to make so you cant delete it either?

Comment: we got something like this, but it is difficult to achieve

Comment: @Thariama i have relized that, i started with this for two days ago and still doesn't know how to do it :p

Comment: okay, i will write an answer showing you the main points of where to take care of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to avoid actions that can remove those images. In cases where you cannot avoid the deletion of images you will have to make sure they get reinserted afterwards at the correct spots. For this you will need a function that checks for images in actual editor selection and another one that takes care of the insertion.

Actions you will need to tweak in order to keep your images (manipulate the caret):

BACKSPACE, ENTF (js keycodes 8 and 46): range is collpassed!

```
// this is tinymce 3 syntax, tinymce 4 looks only a bit different
ed.onKeyDown.add(function onkeydown(ed, e) {
    var rng = ed.selection.getRng();
    if (e.keyCode == 46 && rng.collapsed) { // BACKSPACE
        // manipulate the caret in the editor and set if after the image, in case there are several adjacent images set the caret after all these image
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == 8 && rng.collapsed) { // ENTF
        // manipulate the caret in the editor and set if before the image, in case there are several adjacent images set the caret before all these image
    }

});
```

Well, there are also situation where content is selected and therefor the range is not collapsed (Backspace, Entf, cmd/ctrl+x, cmd/ctrl+v, overwriting of selected content with a character).

In this case you will need to check onKeyDown if there are images inside the selected content. You will need to save them and reinsert those elements after the default browser action.

```
var image_string = '';
var node = ed.selection.getNode();
var $node = $(node);

// checks if a node is inside the range
rangeIntersectsNode: function (range, node) {
    var nodeRange;
    if (range.intersectsNode) {
        return range.intersectsNode(node);
    }
    else {
        nodeRange = tinymce.isIE && !window.is_ie9 ? this.editor.selection.getRng(1) : node.ownerDocument.createRange();
        try {
            nodeRange.selectNode(node);
        } catch (e) {
            nodeRange.selectNodeContents(node);
        }
        return range.compareBoundaryPoints(tinymce.isIE && !window.is_ie9 ? 3 : Range.END_TO_START, nodeRange) == -1 &&
            range.compareBoundaryPoints(tinymce.isIE && !window.is_ie9 ? 1 : Range.START_TO_END, nodeRange) == 1;
    }
},

// save image html to string-variable
$(paragraph).find('img').each(function(){
    if (rangeIntersectsNode(rng, this))
    {
        image_string += $(this).clone().wrap('<div>').parent().html();
    }
});
```

onKeyUp you need to insert this string into the editor

```
tinymce.execCommand('insertHTML', false, image_string);
```

For pasting (ctrl+v) we need a different approach.You will need to use the function (tinymce config param) [paste_preprocess](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3apaste_preprocess).
Check for images inside the selection and use above funytionality, then insert the string directly with the content from pasting:

```
o.content = o.content + image_string;
```

Additionally, be aware of this: You won't be able to intercept deletions occuring over the browser menu without an own browser AddOn.